# Shift focus between buttons in frame using arrow keys?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm new here and I still have a learning relationship with Python and tkinter. For my first project I wanted to build a retro gaming platform, launching from my own collection of games, with a GUI inspired by Netflix. So far, it mostly works as intended: Categories are chosen randomly from a list of all available categories, and based on that, a button is created for each game in the category. Again, this is all working fine.

The problem: Given the nature of the application, it's important that the user be able to control it with either the keyboard or a bluetooth controller. I can set the focus to the first button in the first category, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to actually move the focus from one button to another(left and right), or from one frame to another (up and down) using, for now, the arrow keys. Is there a somewhat simple way of doing this? I've searched for days now and have come up with very little.

Code I have so far:(edit to remove eternal module data)

```
import tkinter as tk

c1i = []
c1b = []
tab_1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]

def populate():
    for i in tab_1:
        new_button = tk.Button(scrl_frame, bd = 0, command = None)
        c1b.append(new_button)
        new_button.pack(side = "left", padx = 5)


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry ("800x1200")
main_frame = tk.Frame(root, height = 1200, width = 800)
main_canvas = tk.Canvas(main_frame, height = 1200, width = 800, bg = "black")
frame_1 = tk.Frame(main_canvas, height = 170, width = 800, bg = "black")
canvas_1 = tk.Canvas(frame_1, height = 170, width = 800, bg = "black")

scrl_frame = tk.Frame(canvas_1, bg = "black")
scrl = tk.Scrollbar(frame_1, orient = "horizontal", bg = "black", command = canvas_1.xview)
scrl_frame.bind("<Configure>", lambda k: canvas_1.configure(scrollregion = canvas_1.bbox("all")))

populate()

canvas_1.create_window((0, 0), window = scrl_frame, anchor = "w")
canvas_1.configure(xscrollcommand = scrl.set)


main_frame.pack(fill = "both", expand = True)
main_canvas.pack(fill = "both", expand = True)
frame_1.pack(fill = "x", side = "bottom")
canvas_1.pack(pady = 5, fill = "both", expand = True)
scrl.pack(fill = "x")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: we can't run your code since you haven't provided a `get_data` module. Is that module really necessary to illustrate the problem, or can you hard-code some sample data into the example?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I edited my code to remove those references for the sake of testing.

Comment: Did you try binding `<Left>` and `<Right>` events to shift focus of buttons, and `<Up>` and `<Down>` events to switch categories?

Comment: I was able to bind the keys to the root and register key presses, I just don't have any idea how to bind them to the focus.

Comment: Since you have already a list `c1b` to hold the buttons, you need to declare a global variable, e.g. `index`, to hold which button in the list is active.  Then in the callback, you adjust `index` based on what key is pressed and call `c1b[index].focus_set()` to shift focus.

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you! I hadn't figured out global variables yet, and tried to do this exact thing but was getting "variable called before reference" errors.

Comment: Guess I can't mark a comment as the answer? If you could repost that as an answer, I'll mark it so you get credit. And thanks again, it was driving me nuts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have already a list `c1b` to hold the buttons, you need to declare a global variable to hold which button in the list is active and another global variable to point to the active button list:

```
index = 0
buttons = c1b
buttons[index].focus_set()  # focus on the first button
```

Then you need to bind `<Left>` and `<Right>` key events to a callback to switch focus:

```
def switch_button(event):
    global index
    if event.keysym == 'Left':
        if index > 0:
            index -= 1
    else:
        if index < len(buttons)-1:
            index += 1
    buttons[index].focus_set()

root.bind('<Left>', switch_button)
root.bind('<Right>', switch_button)
```

Also you need to bind `<Up>` and `<Down>` key events to a callback to switch category:

```
def switch_category(event):
    global index
    if event.keysym == 'Up':
        print('select upper category')
        # set 'buttons' to upper category
    else:
        print('select lower category')
        # set 'buttons' to lower category
    # focus on the first button in the category
    index = 0
    buttons[index].focus_set()

root.bind('<Up>', switch_category)
root.bind('<Down>', switch_category)
```